# Why does my for loop in C# need a semicolon in the condition?

Tags: c#, for-loop

```
for (int frame <= 10; frame++)
{
}
```

For example, I have this code, but it is not working. When I put in a semi colon though, it works. Why is this?

```
for (; frame <= 10; frame++)
{
}
```

Comment: You didn't just add the semi-colon; you also removed the `int`, which fixed a different syntax error as well.

Comment: Btw you should choose an answer below.

Answer (score 5):

C# syntax dictates that the `for` statement has:

1) An initializer

2) A condition

3) An iterator

You don't have to put anything in those sections, but they still need to be there for the sake of the compiler.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx

Edit:
As an aside, you could use a `while` loop instead:

```
while (frame++ <= 10)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your for loop (2nd example) works because you already initialize the variable *frame*
before your for loop start.

for example:

```
int frame = 0;
for(; frame <= 10; frame++)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is how the `for` works. It has three parts

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) documentation:

```
for (initializer; condition; iterator)
    body
```

basically, by putting an extra semicolon, you are giving it a empty initializer part.

Answer (score 1):

because it is the language syntax http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx

```
for (initializer; condition; iterator)
    body
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the for loop's first part is the declaration/initialization, it is optional.  Putting the ; just moves to the next part, the condition.

Comment: If it is optional, what else would I be able to put as the initializer?

Comment: you could declare the variable prior to that line.